# Sort legend/series by value in fusion chart

Tags: sorting, charts, legend, fusioncharts

How to sort the series/legend segments sort by value? Is there any settings in chart/dataset/data object?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if this document will help you to achieve the case

[Sort orderBy](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusioncharts-aspnet-visualization/data-engine/order-by)

[Sort Data](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-data-engine/sort)